# Can't get OpenLDAP and Pam LDAP working at all

Tags: pam, openldap

Yesterday, I set up an OpenLDAP server and tried to configure it to be useful for SSH. Followed these two guides from DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-client-computers-using-ldap-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

That being said, I've been having a lot of issues with authenticating via SSH since yesterday evening. It worked fine in the morning, but not throughout the rest of the day and I have no idea why. I've restored my Linux VM back to a previous snapshot just so that I could try setting it all up again, and still can't get it to go.

Basically, when I run slapd -d 1, there doesn't appear to be anything that stands out, indicating that something's wrong. However, when I try SSH'ing into my local box (which hosts the OpenLDAP server), this is what I see in the /var/log/auth.log file:

```
Dec  4 10:03:46 mybox sshd[17741]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost  user=root
Dec  4 10:03:49 mybox sshd[17741]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 45071 ssh2
```

I can only SSH using credentials that are stored on my SSH server, and it's not authenticating through LDAP. I can login with LDAP through ldapsearch without any problem, so I don't think the problem is with LDAP.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Got things working with the help of a friend (not my stuff). Here's two files that were simply used:

file.ldif (used this with ldapadd)

```
version: 1
dn: dc=dolgen,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
dc: dolgen
o: Some Org
description: A sample domain

dn: ou=people,dc=dolgen,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: cn=Bob Anderson,ou=people,dc=dolgen,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: Bob Anderson
sn: Anderson
uid: test
# the userpassword is set to the SHA1 of 'testtesttest'
userPassword: {SSHA}ih08rDcGRC+S5ol888SZG5YUjOX1oVVK
description: This is Bob
uidNumber: 2000
gidNumber: 1100
homeDirectory: /
loginShell: /bin/sh
```

slapd.conf

```
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema


pidfile         /tmp/slapd.pid
argsfile        /tmp/slapd.args

TLSCertificateFile /tmp/ldap.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile /tmp/ldap.key
moduleload back_hdb.la
database        hdb
suffix          "dc=dolgen,dc=net" 
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=dolgen,dc=net" 
# password is 'testtesttest'
rootpw          {SSHA}ih08rDcGRC+S5ol888SZG5YUjOX1oVVK
# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory       /tmp/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq
```

Comment: Are you trying to login to SSH using `root`?

Comment: Correct. I was able to using root (using both my Linux PW and the PW configured in LDAP), so I feel pretty convinced that it authenticated via LDAP yesterday. Not sure if this isn't what's recommended or not though. Should I create another account instead?

Comment: Can you verify that `PermitRootLogin` is set to True in your `sshd` config file?

Comment: It's set to "yes". I can SSH into root atm using my Linux password just fine though.

Comment: I know, but I like working in layers.  Can you post the content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session`?

Comment: Understandable. thanks for your help thus far. I've edited the original post with the requested configuration files

Comment: As per the tutorial you followed, you forgot to add: `session required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022` to `common-session`.  Also make sure the server info is in `/etc//phpldapadmin/config.php`

Comment: Yep -- I forgot to add it initially, but I've added it now and still nothing so far -- tried restarting services too just in case. Double checked the phpldapadmin config and all of the changes are made there.

Comment: What is the IP Address of the Machine your SSH'ing from, and the IP address of the SSH Server.  The IP Address cannot be localhost

Comment: I was SSH'ing from my own server into my server for testing purposes. I thought localhost was fine since SSH would be authenticating to the LDAP server (itself). Going to modify the configurations using my network IP address and give it another try. Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK, if you're physically at localhost, you cant SSH to localhost... I could be wrong.  Try giving your SSH Server the IP Address of your Server in the `$servers->setValue('server','host'...)` line.

Comment: Yeah it's possible. I tried changing the IP address btw to my network IP address and still getting the same results. Hmm

Comment: Are you using the login form: `LDAP_user@LDAP_client_IP_Address`?

Comment: Yep. ssh root@ldapip

Comment: Grrr, Give me a few hours, and let me set this up on a VM here on my machine, then translate it from GeekSpeak to an answer I'll post it here....  All those things you think will be easy missing configs etc end up biting you :-)

Comment: Thanks. A friend also offered some help and was able to get it up and going for me. Going to have to fiddle around with this more tonight and post an update just of the solution tonight when I get a minute.

Comment: Great... what did we miss??

Comment: I'm able to get it working using his static configuration file but not mine. I'll post them in just a sec. sorry for the delay

Comment: Updated to include the two configuration files that were used to ultimately get this working. I wish I could explain it a little better, but I'm still fairly new to setting up and/or configuring OpenLDAP.

Comment: I can explain, but you need to understand ActiveDirectory to some extent before I do

Comment: Yep. That's where I'm lacking. Lol. I really appreciate your help though, seriously. Just glad this is finally working.

Comment: In Short, AD is Windows Based and doesn't understand the login mechanism used by SSH, but SSH can communicate with AD.  The tutorial you were using assumes that your SSH server existed in a network that wasn't using AD for authentication.  Your friend's static config file contains the information needed to use the AD as a passthrough authentication, including a Database lookup.  2ndly, IIRC 2 `cn's` cannot exist in the same AD forest.  Since your friends real network was configured properly, it was disallowing access to your test.

Comment: thanks :) `<filling up min char limit>`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether /etc/ssh/sshd_config has "UsePAM yes". It basically enables PAM authentication required for OpenLDAP